# Pivot values to existing columns in PySpark data frame

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a data frame like below in pyspark.

```
+---+-------------+----+
| id|       device| val|
+---+-------------+----+
|  3|      mac pro|   1|          
|  1|       iphone|   2|
|  1|android phone|   2|
|  1|   windows pc|   2|
|  1|   spy camera|   2|
|  2|   spy camera|   3|
|  2|       iphone|   3|
|  3|   spy camera|   1|
|  3|         cctv|   1|
+---+-------------+----+
```

I want to populate some columns based on the below `lists`

```
phone_list = ['iphone', 'android phone', 'nokia']
pc_list = ['windows pc', 'mac pro']
security_list = ['spy camera']
ucg_list = ['ipad']
```

I have done like below.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when, lit 
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
df1 = df.withColumn('phones', lit(None).cast(IntegerType())).withColumn('pc', lit(None).cast(IntegerType())).withColumn('security', lit(None).cast(IntegerType())).withColumn('null', lit(None).cast(IntegerType())).withColumn('ucg', lit(None).cast(IntegerType()))

import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df1.withColumn('cat', 
    F.when(df1.device.isin(phone_list), 'phones').otherwise(
    F.when(df1.device.isin(pc_list), 'pc').otherwise(
    F.when(df1.device.isin(security_list), 'security')))
).groupBy('id', 'phones', 'pc', 'security', 'null', 'ucg').pivot('cat').agg(F.count('cat')).show()
```

**output I am receiving**

```
+---+------+----+--------+----+----+----+---+------+--------+
| id|phones|  pc|security|null| ucg|null| pc|phones|security|
+---+------+----+--------+----+----+----+---+------+--------+
|  3|  null|null|    null|null|null|   0|  1|     0|       1|
|  2|  null|null|    null|null|null|   0|  0|     1|       1|
|  1|  null|null|    null|null|null|   0|  1|     2|       1|
+---+------+----+--------+----+----+----+---+------+--------+
```

What I want is to create columns first based on the list names and then populate values

**expected output**

```
+---+------+---+------+--------+----+
| id|   ucg| pc|phones|security|null|
+---+------+---+------+--------+----+
|  1|     0|  1|     2|       1|   0|
|  2|     0|  0|     1|       1|   0|
|  3|     0|  1|     0|       1|   1|
+---+------+---+------+--------+----+
```

How can I get what I want?

**Edit**

when I do the below

```
df1 = df.withColumn('cat', 
    f.when(df.device.isin(phone_list), 'phones').otherwise(
    f.when(df.device.isin(pc_list), 'pc').otherwise(
    f.when(df.device.isin(ucg_list), 'ucg').otherwise(
    f.when(df.device.isin(security_list), 'security')))))
```

The output is

```
+---+-------------+---+--------+
| id|       device|val|     cat|
+---+-------------+---+--------+
|  3|      mac pro|  1|      pc|
|  3|   spy camera|  1|security|
|  3|         cctv|  1|    null|
|  1|       iphone|  2|  phones|
|  1|android phone|  2|  phones|
|  1|   windows pc|  2|      pc|
|  1|   spy camera|  2|security|
|  2|   spy camera|  3|security|
|  2|       iphone|  3|  phones|
+---+-------------+---+--------+
```

In the output you can see that `id` `3` has a `null` value in `cat` column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating and populating `None` for `'phones', 'pc', 'ucg', 'security', 'null'` columns just for `groupBy` doesn't make sense. **Grouping with id and all of the above columns with null or grouping by only id, both are same**.

What you can do instead is find the difference between actual pivoted columns and the intended columns and then create and populate with 0

So the following should work for you

```
phone_list = ['iphone', 'android phone', 'nokia']
pc_list = ['windows pc', 'mac pro']
security_list = ['spy camera']
ucg_list = ['ipad']

from pyspark.sql import functions as f
df = df.withColumn('cat',
               f.when(df.device.isin(phone_list), 'phones').otherwise(
                 f.when(df.device.isin(pc_list), 'pc').otherwise(
                   f.when(df.device.isin(ucg_list), 'ucg').otherwise(
                     f.when(df.device.isin(security_list), 'security'))))
               )\
    .groupBy('id').pivot('cat').agg(f.count('val'))\
    .na.fill(0)\

columnList = ['phones', 'pc', 'ucg', 'security', 'null']
actualcolumnList = df.columns[1:]

diffColumns = [x for x in columnList if x not in actualcolumnList]

for y in diffColumns:
    df = df.withColumn(y, f.lit(0))

df.show(truncate=False)
```

which should give you

```
+---+----+---+------+--------+---+
|id |null|pc |phones|security|ucg|
+---+----+---+------+--------+---+
|3  |1   |1  |0     |1       |0  |
|1  |0   |1  |2     |1       |0  |
|2  |0   |0  |1     |1       |0  |
+---+----+---+------+--------+---+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Just a small bit in my question you can see that I want for `id` `3` `null` column should have `1` value

Comment: why it should be 1 ? can you explain it? @User12345

Comment: I have edited my answer @User12345. it wasn't counting as null is ignored in count function. I have used val column in count function which is not null.